# Добавление элементов в массивы или срезы Golang

Tags: golang

Пытаю мозг и чуть изучаю этот язык, но застрял и не могу понять как сделать.

У меня есть тестовая программа. В ней цикл и после очередной итерации записывается новое значение в переменную.

Например `ipToSt := ip.IP.String()`.
Естественно потом значение перезаписывается. Как мне их все добавить, например, в срез
`slice := []string{}`?
Чтобы на выходе `fmt.Println(slice)` было `[bla1 bla2 bla3 bla4]`?

Comment: https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/15

Comment: `slise = append(slise, ipToStr)`

Answer (score 0):

Добавление элемента в слайс делается функцией append (как уже ответили в комментариях). Я бы хотел еще посоветовать разобраться с устройством слайсов, в сети и в книгах есть много хороших описаний.
Основные моменты:

- слайс - это структура, которая содержит ссылку на данные (начало данных, array), длину (len) и емкость (cap): [slice.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/slice.go#L15)
- append добавляет новый элемент (или элементы) к слайсу, увеличиваю длину, и если не хватает емкости, то увеличивает ее. Для этого выделяется новая область памяти для array и из старой копируются все значения в новую и добавляются новые элементы из вызова append.  Емкость увеличивается сначала в два раза (на 100%) (чтобы избежать большого количества аллокаций и копирования), но если больше 512 элементов плавно уменьшаться до 25% . Код этого алгоритма можно найти здесь: [slice.go](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.4/src/runtime/slice.go#168)
- обратите внимание на случаи когда два слайса указывают на одну область памяти (в array одинаковый адрес). Такое часто происходит при [реслайсинге](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/7), например, или при передаче слайса в функцию либо и т.п.